# Xperia Z5 Premium - Power button not working - can't get into fastboot mode?

Tags: android, adb, sony, sony-xperia

I really hope somebody can help me with this.

I have xperia z5 premium, power button stopped working a month ago or something, but the phone was working perfectly fine. Of course, I made a mistake and did not charge it in time and it turned off. Now I can't get it to turn back on because the button is not working.

I explored all my options and I realized I can do fastboot reboot through fastboot and adb. However, I can't seem to get my phone to go into fastboot mode.

I hold volume up button (which I know for a fact is working), I plugin usb, and instead of getting that blue led light everybody keeps talking about, I just get a red led and then a green one after the sony logo that signals the phone is charging.

I installed ADB and xperia z5 premium drivers and I still can't get it to work. When I type fastboot reboot it says  when I try adb reboot or adb reboot bootloader it says "error: device not found".

I've also installed xperia companion app and when I plugin my phone it shows a screen where it says: "Your device is locked

1. Unlock require
   Unlock the device using password or fingerpint if needed
2. Allow data access
   On your device, select the option to allow data access"

I've tried doing the same thing with adb on two different pcs, always get the same result. Phone just gets to charging screen and keeps charging instead of going into any mode.

I also tried holding volume down button and plugging in usb which is supposed to be recovery mode or something, but that doesnt work either, I also get charging screen. And I'm 100% sure both my volume up and volume down buttons are working.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S - Debugging mode is not on, im 100% sure since i never turned it on.

Somebody please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try downloading the sony xperia flashtool and boot your device in fastboot mode by holding down the volume down button and inserting the usb cable a blue light should appear, open up the flash tool and wait for the device to be detected if not detected, goto c drive then inside the flashtool folder there should be a folder named drivers, open it up then install the drivers for your device. back to the flashtool... when your device is detected, click on the lightning bolt icon and select fast boot mode, then you should see a window pop up and click reboot device into system.

hope this solves your problem